# Updating Installed Program Version when using binary patch?

Tags: windows, binary, diff, patch

So i'm looking into the idea of using something like bsdiff to create very small and automatic patches. One limitation i notices is it won't update the installed version number that is show in Programs and Features in win7. Is there some way you can manually update this, any api's you should be using? and any other things you should consider, obviously things like UAC will need to be considered.

Comment: The Windows Installer and MSI technology supports "patching" via MSP files.  WIX is an ok front end to all this: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Bevan's answer on 64bit machines the path could be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

I'm not sure if Current user also has this structure

Answer (score 2):

The version number in Programs and Features or Add/Remove Program Files comes from a registry entry rather than from a file.

Under one of these keys there will be the application's uninstall subkey.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Updating the DisplayVersion registry value under this key will change the version number in Programs and Features or Add/Remove Program files.

Comment: I don't seem to see our software in either of those locations. It normally installs via Install Shield but i would have thought their was some central location that represents your installed apps.

Comment: I think i found it. Seems like on 64bit you need to consider this path
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall